# Generating data to follow given variogram 

Tags: spatial, random-generation, variogram

It is a straightforward approach having a set of coordinates (e.g., in 2D as `{x,y}`) and at least an associated variable (e.g., `v`) to calculate a **variogram** as a descriptor of the spatial dependency of the variable `v` through the field being studied.

[image]
[image]

The question appeared to me is:
**how to generate a realization of a dataset having a variogram? (inverse move!)**
That is, there is at least one variogram available but neither dataset nor other description is available and the goal is to generate a realization of original (unknown) dataset that could have such a variogram.
What is the probability of having such a realization?

**Updates / Comments:**
From `variogram` in the above context I mean empirical variogram. I suppose that fitting a variogram model is not an issue at least for this question. 
Also variogram is available as pairs (h, gamma).

Comment: By variogram, you mean variogram **model**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sequential simulation to generate realizations of a random field that has the covariance structure given in the variogram model. In R this can be done using gstat. See demo(ugsim) and demo(uisim) from R code examples from gstat.

Comment: +1 First, of course, you have to fit a variogram model to the empirical variogram shown.  Note that `geoR` easily performs simulations too.

Comment: But I assume that the OP has a variogram already. Or else this would be a chicken and egg problem :).

Comment: The graphic in the question, Paul, shows an empirical variogram, not a variogram model.  You cannot use an empirical variogram directly to drive a stochastic simulation (it wouldn't be positive definite, so the simulation would likely run into numerical problems).  But there's no chicken/egg problem: one fits the variogram model to this empirical variogram and then proceeds.  Some information is lost--a good variographic analysis considers much more than a single empirical variogram *in vacuo* --but that can't be helped here.

Comment: By chicken and egg I mean that without data to fit the variogram model, there is no variogram model to generate new data. And by variogram, I mean variogram model.

Comment: I think we are circling around two interpretations of the question, which unfortunately makes no distinction between *model* variogram and *empirical* variogram.  Although it illustrates an empirical variogram (and so that's how I understand every occurrence of "variogram" in the question), it very well could be referring to a model variogram, in which case you are perfectly right.

Comment: That happens all the time, also in journal papers :). From an empirical variogram it would be impossible to generate a new dataset, I think.

Comment: Actually, an empirical variogram is just fine: fit a model to it and proceed.  I admit it is not easy to do the fitting when presented with just a graphic (but it can be done!), but if the actual values behind the right-hand graphic in the question were available, the process would be straightforward.

Comment: Part of my PhD was spent on automatic variogram fitting, so I think it is possible ;)

Comment: @whuber and Paul: Thanks you both. A very good discussion. I made it clear so as updates in the question.